# pip install virtualenwrapper permission denied error on mac OSX Lion

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, virtualenvwrapper

I'm new to programming--loving it. On mac OSX Lion I've installed virtualenv with pip and it works. 
But pip install virtualenvwrapper shows warnings and then error: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenvwrapper: Permission denied

> $ pip install virtualenvwrapper Downloading/unpacking
>   virtualenvwrapper   Downloading virtualenvwrapper-4.1.1.tar.gz (81kB):
>   81kB downloaded   Running setup.py egg_info for package
>   virtualenvwrapper
>
> ```
> Installed /private/var/folders/6v/3cyz6tp514b2mqt02wc8x9k40000gn/T/pip_build_lynnrasmussen/virtualenvwrapper/pbr-0.5.23-py2.7.egg
> [pbr] Processing SOURCES.txt
> warning: LocalManifestMaker: standard file '-c' not found
>
> warning: no files found matching 'AUTHORS'
> warning: no files found matching 'ChangeLog'
> warning: no previously-included files found matching '.gitignore'
> warning: no previously-included files found matching '.gitreview'
> warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
> warning: no files found matching '*.html' under directory 'docs'
> warning: no files found matching '*.css' under directory 'docs'
> warning: no files found matching '*.js' under directory 'docs'
> warning: no files found matching '*.png' under directory 'docs' Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): virtualenv
> ```
>
> in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from virtualenvwrapper)
>   Downloading/unpacking virtualenv-clone (from virtualenvwrapper)
>   Downloading virtualenv-clone-0.2.4.tar.gz   Running setup.py egg_info
>   for package virtualenv-clone
>        Downloading/unpacking stevedore (from virtualenvwrapper)   Downloading stevedore-0.13.tar.gz (760kB): 760kB downloaded   Running
>   setup.py egg_info for package stevedore
>
> ```
> Installed /private/var/folders/6v/3cyz6tp514b2mqt02wc8x9k40000gn/T/pip_build_lynnrasmussen/stevedore/pbr-0.5.23-py2.7.egg
> [pbr] Processing SOURCES.txt
> warning: LocalManifestMaker: standard file '-c' not found
>
> warning: no previously-included files found matching '.gitignore'
> warning: no previously-included files found matching '.gitreview'
> warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
> warning: no files found matching '*.py' under directory 'tests' Installing collected packages: virtualenvwrapper, virtualenv-clone,
> ```
>
> stevedore   Running setup.py install for virtualenvwrapper
>       [pbr] Reusing existing SOURCES.txt
>       changing mode of build/scripts-2.7/virtualenvwrapper.sh from 644 to 755
>       changing mode of build/scripts-2.7/virtualenvwrapper_lazy.sh from 644 to 755
>       Skipping installation of /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenvwrapper/**init**.py
>   (namespace package)
>       error: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenvwrapper: Permission denied
>       Complete output from command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools;**file**='/private/var/folders/6v/3cyz6tp514b2mqt02wc8x9k40000gn/T/pip_build_lynnrasmussen/virtualenvwrapper/setup.py';exec(compile(open(**file**).read().replace('\r\n',
>   '\n'), **file**, 'exec'))" install --record
>   /var/folders/6v/3cyz6tp514b2mqt02wc8x9k40000gn/T/pip-EJKEQQ-record/install-record.txt
>   --single-version-externally-managed:
>       running install
>
> running build
>
> running build_py
>
> creating build
>
> creating build/lib
>
> creating build/lib/virtualenvwrapper
>
> copying virtualenvwrapper/**init**.py -> build/lib/virtualenvwrapper
>
> copying virtualenvwrapper/hook_loader.py ->
>   build/lib/virtualenvwrapper
>
> copying virtualenvwrapper/project.py -> build/lib/virtualenvwrapper
>
> copying virtualenvwrapper/user_scripts.py ->
>   build/lib/virtualenvwrapper
>
> running egg_info
>
> writing requirements to virtualenvwrapper.egg-info/requires.txt
>
> writing virtualenvwrapper.egg-info/PKG-INFO
>
> writing namespace_packages to
>   virtualenvwrapper.egg-info/namespace_packages.txt
>
> writing top-level names to virtualenvwrapper.egg-info/top_level.txt
>
> writing dependency_links to
>   virtualenvwrapper.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
>
> writing entry points to virtualenvwrapper.egg-info/entry_points.txt
>
> [pbr] Reusing existing SOURCES.txt
>
> running build_scripts
>
> creating build/scripts-2.7
>
> copying virtualenvwrapper.sh -> build/scripts-2.7
>
> copying virtualenvwrapper_lazy.sh -> build/scripts-2.7
>
> changing mode of build/scripts-2.7/virtualenvwrapper.sh from 644 to
>   755
>
> changing mode of build/scripts-2.7/virtualenvwrapper_lazy.sh from 644
>   to 755
>
> running install_lib
>
> Skipping installation of
>   /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenvwrapper/**init**.py
>   (namespace package)
>
> copying virtualenvwrapper/hook_loader.py ->
>   /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenvwrapper
>
> error: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenvwrapper: Permission
>   denied
>
> ---

Answer (score 2):

You should install as Super User.

Try :

`sudo pip install virtualenvwrapper`